# Stuck and confused on conversion factor

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I recently started learning C# and came across this practice question:

Given the distance in miles and km I am supposed to find the greater distance and return the value.

```
public static double Test8(double miles, double kilometers)
{
    double MtoKM = (1 miles = 1.609 kilometers);
    if (miles > kilometers)
    {
        MtoKM = miles;
    }
    return MtoKM; 
}
```

Any clue what I did wrong or hints?

Comment: Why do you think that you did something wrong?

Comment: First of all your are comparing two different units

Comment: All of the invalid code aside, take a look at this from a mathematical perspective. `1 miles = 1.609 kilometers` is sure enough a valid statement, but it doesn't produce a value you can actually work with. In order to do that you first have to decide whether you want to convert to miles or kilometers, then you have to get rid of that equal sign. We do this by dividing one component by the other, `1.609 km / 1 mi`. The suffixes are just informing us about the units we're working with and can technically be removed: `1.609 / 1` = `1.609`. Now you have a value you can work with: `MtoKM = 1.609`

Comment: `double MtoKM = (1 miles = 1.609 kilometers);` - are you asking why this is invalid c# syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd have written it like this, in the interest of being a bit more self documenting:

```
public static double GetGreaterOf(double miles, double kilometers)
{
    double milesInKm = miles * 1.609;
    if (milesInKm > kilometers) {
        return miles;
    } else {
        return kilometers; 
    }
}
```

You could shorten it to:

```
public static double GetGreaterOf(double miles, double kilometers) =>
    miles * 1.609 > kilometers ? miles : kilometers;
```

But brevity doesn't not always correlate with clarity.. ;)